# Building a presentation video

Tags: video, video-editor, composing, greenscreen, tutorial

Hi everyone I am in my last three days before I present my final project for my exam at college everything is ready for the final presentation except a good presentation. At first I made one in Microsoft Power Point but it isn't very cool looking.

I just got an idea for the presentation to create a video that slide's different images that contain information about my project, add some music in the background and at some point the music's volume will be turned lower and an mp3 with me talking will start playing.

Until now it isn't something I could not do in power point although I hope you guys will suggest another software because I also want to add over the presentation another video with me talking and pointing my hand on different subjects from the video. I have never done this before and do not know how am I supposed to cut that part with me talking from one video and add it over another.

Can anyone suggest a good easy to learn software that can achieve this and has an easy learning curve? And also some tutorials on that. Can a beginner like me manage to do it in 3 days?

I would like to make something like this:

Anyone know a tutorial that teaches how to make a similar video?

Comment: This video seems very out-of-touch with current advertising and sales videos. It may just be me, but seeing poorly made advertisements (with the fade in of pictures or cheap animations) make me lose interest immediately. If you really want it to stick out, add in some creativity into it. Food for thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[On this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259425/building-a-presentation-video/11266926#11266926) @hasanyasin and I provided you with alternatives for slideshow presentations. Additionally I place here a part of my answer, just for your convenience:

> Anyway, what you wish to do in a video can be achieved by a
>   professional non linear editing system, like Sony Vegas or Adobe
>   Premiere, of which Sony Vegas is the easiest to learn.
>
> If you are used to Microsoft Based Products (PhotoShop, Corel Draw,
>   Office, Movie Maker, etc.) you are almost ready to do it.
>
> The process to place you in front of the moving images, videos,
>   transitions, text and other media is called "Chroma Key" and it can be
>   reached in the Effects tab of the Sony Vegas 8 (and previous/further
>   versions). A video tutorials on how to create the Chroma Key effect
>   can be found on youtube by dropping the terms "chroma key sony vegas",
>   here is an example:
>
> Basically you work in multi layer. Placing in a time line the elements
>   in the order that you wish them to appear on screen, adding a
>   background, in/out transitions, and other elements. Remember that the
>   top layer will be the "front" element on screen. After which you
>   insert your blue/green screen video at the very top, apply the Chroma
>   Key effect, choose the dropper and select the background in your
>   video, after which you adjust the threshold in order not to appear
>   like a ghost in the video.
>
> You will need to use the "Event Pan and Crop" tool in order to create
>   the "moving" effect for some static items, like pictures and even if
>   you wish your videos to "fly" around the screen. Just run a search in
>   youtube with the words "Pan and Crop Sony Vegas" and you will get tons
>   of results. Here is an example:
>
> And yes...  you can create awesome results in a couple of hours. Give
>   it a try and drop us back a link with your published video.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think one can do this with some helpers, and if 3 days means working 72 hours.

For getting this result you need:

- A editing or compositing software.
- A green- or bluescreen- backdrop.
- Four adujstable Lightsources.
- A room with a depth of about 4-6 meters.